# c program to find pythagorean triples

Tags: c, pythagorean

```
int a,b,n;

printf("Input Natural Number n (n<2,100,000,000) : ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(a=1;a<=100;a++)
    for(b=1;b<=100;b++)

        if(a<b && a*a + b*b == n*n)
        {
            printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n",a,b,n);
        }
        /*else
        {
            printf("impossible \n");
        }
          */         
        return 0;
```

if I delete 'else' the program runs correctly. But I want to make another function which can check the number has pythagorean numbers or not by using 'else' paragraph. But when I put 'else' paragraph in that code, the result is dizzy.... plz help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Put braces around the nested code blocks.

```
int a, b, n;
int impossible = 1;

printf("Input Natural Number n      (n<2,100,000,000) : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (a = 1; a <= 100; a++) {
    for (b = 1; b <= 100; b++) {

        if (a < b && a * a + b * b == n * n) {
            printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", a, b, n);
            impossible = 0;
        }
    }
}

if (impossible == 1) printf("impossible \n");

return 0;
```

Comment: thanks for replying my question. but If I do that as you inform to me, the word 'impossible' will output n 100 times..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int base, int power);

int main(){
    int N;
    
    printf("INput the Num: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    int a, b, c;
    for(a = 0; a < N ; a++) {
        for(b = 0; b< N; b++) {
            if ((a < b) && (b < N - a - b)) {
                if (power(a, 2) + power(b, 2) == power(N - a - b, 2)) {
                    printf("%d^2 + %d^2 = %d^2 \n", a, b, N-a-b);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


int power(int base, int power) {
    int result = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < power ; i++) {
        result *= base;
    }
    return  result;
    
}
```